# Adjust Figure in Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following plot which has variable `X` and `Y` values. In order to explain the issue I have assigend constant values for `X` and `Y` in the code below.

I want that the figure coordinates will start from `(0,0)` and also how can I put the text values`(a,b,Sxy,r,R^2)` under each other and not next to each other as showen below.

Note that I can't use specific values of `X,Y` because they are variable. So thats why I have to use `min()` and `max()` functions as coordinates to show the text values on upper left corner.

code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
X = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
A = 2
plot(X,X**2+A*X+2,'b-')
text(min(X), max(X**2+A*X+2),r'a=12, b=2.09 $S_{xy}$= 0.71 r= 0.9 $R^2$= 0.85',fontsize=12,fontweight='bold')
xlabel('X_value')
ylabel('Y_value')

grid(True)
show()
```

[image]

Comment: for text part just use `\n` in your string and it will break it into lines.

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"? Do you get any error? Does the output, not match with your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem 1:

set `xlim` and `ylim`:

```
plt.xlim((0,max(X)))
plt.ylim((0,max(X**2+A*X+2)))
```

## Problem 2:

use `\n` for newlines, and use `verticalalignment='top'`:

```
plt.text(min(X), max(X**2+A*X+2),'a=12\nb=2.09\n$S_{xy}$= 0.71\nr= 0.9\n$R^2$= 0.85',fontsize=12,fontweight='bold', verticalalignment='top')
```

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
A = 2
plt.plot(X,X**2+A*X+2,'b-')
plt.text(min(X), max(X**2+A*X+2),'a=12\nb=2.09\n$S_{xy}$= 0.71\nr= 0.9\n$R^2$= 0.85',fontsize=12,fontweight='bold', verticalalignment='top')
plt.xlabel('X_value')
plt.ylabel('Y_value')
plt.xlim((0,max(X)))
plt.ylim((0,max(X**2+A*X+2)))


plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the text just remove the raw character and set the vertical alignment to top.
for the limit it's better to just change the minimum rather than a range.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.arange(0,10,0.1)
A = 2
plt.plot(X,X**2+A*X+2,'b-')
plt.text(min(X), max(X**2+A*X+2),'a=12,\nb=2.09\n $S_{xy}$= 0.71\n r= 0.9\n $R^2$= 0.85',fontsize=12,fontweight='bold',va='top')
plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xlabel('X_value')
plt.ylabel('Y_value')
```